# Rshiny App displaying wrong script

Tags: r, oracle, shiny

Please forgive me if this question is not worded efficiently; this is my first time posting a question. 
I am a writing a Shiny App, and it has been going pretty well until a few days ago. I have encountered a problem where, whenever I run the app, an output is displayed that does not match my app at all. Rather, the output appears to be related to the last script a ran (whatever that may be.
Here is my code:

`
     library(shiny)
     library(shinyBS)

```
shinyUi= fluidPage()

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`

and here is my server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have no idea what is causing shiny to display the wrong result rather than the result from the script I am actually running.
If anyone has any suggestions on how I could isolate or fix the problem, I would be very thankful.

EDIT:
Since my question has been answered, and it turns out that the large majority of my posted code was superfluous, I've gone ahead and stripped it down to the bare bones. That should make it more concise. 
  [

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this app consists of two seperate files `Ui.R` and `server.R` and you run it by pressing a button `runapp` in RStudio, you should remove in both scripts the last line

`shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

because it runs a shiny app you defined before - this app from the screenshot which is defined in terms of `ui` and `server` variables. You should also change the first line in `Ui.R` from

```
shinyUi= fluidPage(` to fluidPage(
```

Now after pressing `runapp` button the app should work fine.

---

The other possibility is to overwrite `ui` and `server` variables and run it via `shinyApp` (as a one-file shiny app). Just copy two parts of the app to the same script and then change

```
    shinyUi= fluidPage( to ui <- fluidPage(
```

and

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
```

at the end just execute

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have removed the shinyApp statements at the end of my scripts, and this appears to have fixed my problem. You're the best!